# "Would not pass" or "would not have passed"?

Tags: grammar, tenses, subjunctive-mood

Here is a situation:

(Jack and Dorothy are in the car)

Silence. They pass Blumergton. Dorothy looks out of the window, her face is obviously surprised.

Silence again. They pass Himilgreens.

Silence again.

Jack: "I must tell you something"

Dorothy: "What is it?"

Jack: "We are not going to Darwinhill"

Dorothy: "I know that"

Jack: "How come you know that?"

Dorothy: "Otherwise we would've not passed Blumergton"

or should it be "Otherwise we would not pass Blumergton" or should it be some other way?

Comment: You already got "would not have passed" correctly in your question title, but in the body changed it to "would've not passed". :-)

Comment: and how about will ? what is the differences. will not passed Blumergton.

Comment: I think "will not passed" is not correct. Perhaps, it would be correct with "have":  "We will not have passed Blumergton until midnight", but in this case it will be a reference to the future, while in my question they talk about the past.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be

> Otherwise we would not have passed Blumergton

Normally, you would not separate *would* and *not* in that sentence.

Comment: Also, in normal speech you would say *wouldn't have* instead of *would not have*.